# 404 error while connecting backend to frontend in vercel deployment

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, vite, vercel

I am trying to deploy a MERN stack application on vercel and my backend is deployed fine and I can check the get and post requests in Postman but when I try to fetch data using my React frontend it works fine locally but breaks in my deployment

github (frontend):- https://github.com/vineetkhemnani/Threads_project 
github (backend):- https://github.com/vineetkhemnani/threads_backend 
frontend:- https://threads-project-n34l.vercel.app/auth 
backend:- https://dhaage-backend.vercel.app/

my env file looks like this:-

```
PORT=5000
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.r4mnypa.mongodb.net/threads?retryWrites=true&w=majority
JWT_SECRET=jwt
```

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjkXf.png)

I have setup the proxy in vite config and added all env variables in the backend